# MS SQL: How to design a table where row(s) can reference row(s) within same table

Tags: sql, database, reference, entity

I have a design task in which I would like to store a relationship between one entity and many other entities. A given entity X may be connected to one or many entities Y. All entities are stored in the same table. I am looking for the correct (in data normalisation terms) way of representing this relationship in MS SQL database.

I have just touched on "junction tables" that serve as a reference point between 2 separate entities (by enforcing key constraints), however my brain fails to see how I can reuse this technique for my problem where all entities are stored in the same table.

Regards,
Sergiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample schema for what you are trying to achieve. This is for mySQL, but it should be enough to give you the genreal idea.
Every 'Node' (entity in your case) is of a particular type and the relationshsips between nodes are stored in the NodeLinkNode table. Each relatinship is of a particular type, as defined in the 'LinkType' table.

```
CREATE TABLE NodeType
(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Node
(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Title TEXT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Node_NodeType FOREIGN KEY (NodeTypeID) REFERENCES NodeType(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE LinkType
(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE NodeLinkNode
(
  FirstNodeId INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    SecondNodeId INTEGER NOT NULL , 
    LinkTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (LinkTypeID, FirstNodeId, SecondNodeId), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_NodeLinkGroup_Node FOREIGN KEY (FirstNodeId) REFERENCES Node(Id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_NodeLinkGroup_Group FOREIGN KEY (SecondNodeId) REFERENCES Node(Id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_NodeLinkGroup_Type FOREIGN KEY (LinkTypeId) REFERENCES LinkType(Id)
);
```

Comment: I see thank you! I used your example to inspire below:
 `CREATE TABLE Site (
  ID int primary key,
  Name varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE SiteNeighbours (
  ParentSiteID int references Site (ID),
  ChildrenSiteID int references Site (ID),
  constraint pk_SiteNeighbours primary key (ParentSiteID, ChildrenSiteID)
)`

Answer (score 0):

For convenience: here is the code that works in MS SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Site (    
    ID int primary key,    
    Name varchar(30)    
)

CREATE TABLE SiteNeighbours (    
  ParentSiteID int references Site (ID),    
  ChildrenSiteID int references Site (ID),    
  constraint pk_SiteNeighbours primary key (ParentSiteID, ChildrenSiteID)
)
```

Code creates a Site table an a SiteNeighbours table. The latter stores relationships of Sites as per my question above.
The meat is the constraint we lay on the table, whereby primary key pairs in the table have to be unique. This constraints duplicate data and keeps our relationship list's integrity intact.

If you insert a relationship that already exists, an exception is thrown by MSSQL engine.